# Turning CKEditor 4 inline editing on and off with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I need to be able to toggle inline editing on/off with a button. See here for example of inline editing: http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/3559/samples/inlineall.html

My markup is as so:

```
<div contenteditable='true'>Mycontent</div>
```

Using jQuery I want to be able to turn on/off the editor.

I have tried setting `contenteditable` to false, but this does not work. The editor is not loading back into the page on toggling the `contenteditable` setting.

Addendum: I also needed to destroy all CKEditor inline instances on a button click. Here is how I did that:

```
        //kill all ckeditors
        for(k in CKEDITOR.instances){
            var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[k];
            instance.destroy();
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery won't help you. Use CKEditor's API. E.g. you can destroy editor each time you want to turn it off (see http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy) and initialize again to turn it on. There may be other ways to "turn editor off", but you'd have to be more precise what does it mean for you.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed destroy it. How to I instantiate the inline editor again though?

Comment: I wanted to write that, exactly the same way you instantiated it the first time, but then I thought that it's instantiating automatically :D. Anyway - `CKEDITOR.inline( 'div_id' )`. Check [this demo](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/3559/samples/inlinebycode.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but after inline instance is destroyed, although the toolbars disappear, the editor area is still editable. Also the blinking cursor is there. How can I make it work like before CKEDITOR.inline(); - I mean static content.

Comment: ops. found it.     `<html element>.setAttribute('contenteditable',"false");`
does the job