# CKEditor inline editing: how to enable and disable it clicking on a button

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, contenteditable, inline-editing

I have CKEditor in my page, and I want to use it in *InlineEditing* mode on some `DIVs` on which I dinamically set `contenteditable='true'` attribute.

For each editable DIV, I have a button than toggle on it `contenteditable` to `'true'` and `'false'`, in order to enable or disable editing

Following [official documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery), first of all I set this:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

Then, I set editability of each DIV:

```
$('.toggle-edit').click(function(e){ 
  var editedDiv = '#' + $(this).data('editTarget');

  if( $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable') == 'true' )
  {
    $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','false');
    $(this).text('Start Editing');
  }
  else
  {
    $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','true');
    $(editedDiv).ckeditor();
    $(this).text('Finish Editing');
  }
});
```

This runs, but when I set `contenteditable='false'` clicking again on button, `DIV` is not editable anymore, but clicking on it, will continue to launch *CKEditor* (I think in a *Read-Only* Mode).

How to avoid this in the simpler way? So, toggle not only editability but also CKEditor activation?

---

**UPDATE:**
I tried to adapt solution taken by [this past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845850/turning-ckeditor-4-inline-editing-on-and-off-with-javascript), writing following code:

```
$('.toggle-edit').click(function(e){ 
  var id_editedDiv = $(this).data('editTarget');
  var editedDiv = '#' + id_editedDiv;

  if( $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable') == 'true' )
  {
    $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','false');
    CKEDITOR.instances.id_editedDiv.destroy();
    $(this).text('Start Editing');
  }
  else
  {
    $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','true');
    CKEDITOR.inline( id_editedDiv );
    $(this).text('Finish Editing');
  }
});
```

But, again, nothing happens. CKeditor is created clicking `.toggle-edit` button, but then it is not destroyed when `contenteditable` is again set to `false` (and it opens in read-only mode).

Comment: Correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457071/how-to-disable-ckeditor-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

I was just working on a similar problem and here's what worked for me (applying my fix to your code):

```
var editor;

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    editor = ev.editor;
    // you can also add more config for this instance of CKE here
    // e.g. editor.setReadOnly(false);
});

$('.toggle-edit').click(function(e){ 
    var id_editedDiv = $(this).data('editTarget');
    var editedDiv = '#' + id_editedDiv;

    if($(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable') === 'true'){
        $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','false');
        editor.destroy();
        $(this).text('Start Editing');
    }
    else {
        $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','true');
        CKEDITOR.inline(id_editedDiv);
        $(this).text('Finish Editing');
    }
});
```

If you have several active instances of CKE you should adjust that obviously, but you should get the idea!